# Is there an R function or command for making row labels the same as some element in a column?

Tags: r, sorting, statistics

I have a data frame that has row numbers, 1-250, and incident ID numbers in the format inc_1, inc_2, inc-3, etc... Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMUsV.png) of the data frame. The data is a table with 3 columns and 250 rows, a bit like this:

```
row number| officer |  incident ID
__________|_________|_____________
98        |    AT   |    inc_1
124       |    DG   |    inc_10
125       |    RB   |    inc_101
```

I'd like the row number to be the same as the incident number.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @neilfws, makes things much clearer

Comment: To clarify: do you want the row names to be the same as `incident ID`, or the same as the numerical portion of `incident ID` (1, 10, 101) ?

Comment: The same as the numerical portion. However, I don't want to lose the inc label because I will need to merge it with another data frame, based on the inc (incident no) column. I've been reading on matrices for ages but I have a feeling this must be an easier task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `sub` to extract the incident number and assign it to rownames.

```
rownames(df) <- sub(".*_", "", df$incident_ID)
#Some other variations include
#rownames(df) <- sub("inc_", "", df$incident_ID)
#rownames(df) <- sub("\\D+", "", df$incident_ID)
#rownames(df) <- sub(".*?(\\d+)", "\\1", df$incident_ID)

df
#    officer incident_ID
#1        AT       inc_1
#10       DG      inc_10
#101      RB     inc_101
```

---

Also we can `parse_number` from `readr` to extract the numeric part

```
rownames(df) <- readr::parse_number(df$incident_ID)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(officer = c("AT", "DG", "RB"), incident_ID = c("inc_1", 
"inc_10", "inc_101")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran this command rownames(df) <- sub(".*_", "", df$incident_ID) and it returns error >Error in df$incident_ID : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @DianaSisu Mostly because your dataframe is not called `df`, it is named something else. What is the name of your dataframe?

Comment: This one did it: rownames(officer_inc) <- sub("\\D+", "", officer_inc$incident_id)

Comment: Yes, embarrassing, I know. First I didn't change the name of the data frame. Then I didn't check the name of the field (ID was lower case). Please forgive me, it is 3.21 am in the UK. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I can't sort the data by rownames column. The error I get is >Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length

Comment: How are you sorting it? What is the code that you are using? Try `df[order(as.integer(rownames(df))), ]` after you have assigned the rownames from above.

Comment: I was sorting it by viewing the file. It works now. I thought the rownames would be treated as integers by the viewer, same as in the other data frame I have. The command works, thanks.

Comment: Rownames are not columns of the dataframe and they are stored as characters so you need to convert it to integer before sorting/ordering them.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the `inc` number using strsplit:

```
f <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c('inc_1', 'inc_10', 'inc_12'))
row.names(f) <- sapply(as.character(f$b), function(x) strsplit(x,"_")[[1]][2])
> f
   a      b
1  1  inc_1
10 2 inc_10
12 3 inc_12
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much @asafpr! Before I go and toy with this and try to make sense of it, can I a make sure it doesn't change the number of the case, yes? It makes the number of the row the same as the number of the case, not vice-versa. Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Yes, it will split the case number and use the number as the new row names